# Error with "__str__ returned non-string (type int)"

Tags: python, django-models, django-admin

I have a problem with a Django Project.

I'll be direct. I am connecting my Django admin to a database that I have on a server, the problem is that when accessing the models in the browser, throws the following error:

```
TypeError at /admin/crm/asentamiento/78967/
__str__ returned non-string (type int)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/crm/asentamiento/78967/
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__str__ returned non-string (type int)
Exception Location: C:\Spameando\crm_denue2\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py in force_text, line 90
Python Executable:  C:\Spameando\crm_denue2\myvenv\Scripts\python3.exe
Python Version: 3.4.4
```

And the code for my model is this:

```
class Asentamiento(models.Model):
    id_asentamiento = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nom_asentamiento = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    tipo_centro = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nom_centro = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    num_local = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    tipo_asentamiento_id_tipo_asent = models.ForeignKey('TipoAsentamiento', db_column='tipo_asentamiento_id_tipo_asent')
    codigo_postal_id_codpostal = models.ForeignKey('CodigoPostal', db_column='codigo_postal_id_codpostal')
    localidad_id_localidad = models.ForeignKey('Localidad', db_column='localidad_id_localidad')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'asentamiento'

    def __str__(self):
            return self.nom_asentamiento
```

I have no idea what the problem is, since I have done the model many times and I always throw the same error, in all other tables and models I have no problem.

The error occurs when I click on some value of my model to see in a window the selected value.

Comment: Do you know what `__str__` is for?

Comment: The `__str__` magic method must return a `str`.  You can solve this with `return str(self.nom_asentamiento)`

Comment: Believe me, I did it from the beginning and it did not work, I also thought it was for something else in that return but nope.

Comment: @Edgar González I think no problem with your model because it is a `CharField` no need to convert it to string type. so, try to make migrations  for app and apply them.

Answer (score 21):

Just put `str()` here:

```
def __str__(self):
       return str(self.nom_asentamiento)
```

Comment: Ah, some one just commented this too.

Comment: I had changed it before and it still has the same error.

Comment: Why would `str()` be returning anything other than a string? Are you sure it's the same error?

Comment: What is `self.nom_asentamiento`'s type? EDIT: nvm, it's a `CharField`

Comment: Is the error coming from your `__str__()` definition, or the `__str__()` definition for `models.CharField`?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this will help, I had a similar problem recently:

```
def __str__(self):
   return 'Asentamiento: {} {} {} {} {} '.format(self.id_asentamiento, self.nom_asentamiento, self.tipo_centro, self.nom_centro, self.num_local)
```

I hope it works for you, regards

Answer (score 2):

Here you're not getting this error because of the return type of **Asentamiento** model. It return CharField not an Integer type (as mentioned in the error message.)

The error may be due to the return type of ***TipoAsentamiento***, ***CodigoPostal*** or the ***Localidad*** model. Since these models have *One to Many Relationship* with the **Asentamiento** model.

If you're not sure about the return types of these models, then you need to add `__str__()` method in the model and return a CharField or any other non integer field.

For example, If you want to return a **PositiveIntegerField**,

```
def __str__(self):
   return str(self.positive_integer_field_name)
# here, you need to use the str() method to convert the return type into a string.
```

If you want to return a Non Integer Field,

```
def __str__(self):
   return self.non_integer_field_name
```

Answer (score 1):

I had default code created by `VSCode`, which was returning `pk`.

Changed

```
  def __str__(self):
      return self.pk
```

to:

```
  def __str__(self):
      return self.title # title is the field from my model
```

Answer (score 0):

For me its because i returned object instead of string, so i changed

```
 def __str__(self):
    return self.user
```

to

```
 def __str__(self):
    return self.user.email
```

Answer (score 0):

I just face this issue and I think if we put `str()` before `self.field` will not solve our problem. even tho I commented out that `__str__` method after running the migrations command I'm facing this issue again and again.

issue cause:-

the main issue is with your other model that is having any relationship to this model and in that model, you are doing as usual `__str__` method!

you should check put `str()` before that model that is having Manytoone relation ship with your model!

Answer (score 0):

I use which field we want to represent in our admin pannel.
Put that field in a string representation, in my case:

```
def__str__:
  return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue could arise if one of the foreign key fields returns `models.IntegerField()`. This happened to me, and I had to be sure that the foreign keys also returned `models.Charfield()` types.

Answer (score 0):

in models example:

class tests(models.Model):
jw = models.IntegerField()

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.jw)
```